# cutting a directory name with multiple instances of the same delimiter (Shell)

Tags: cut

I have directories I want to rename,
for example: `10-00017_S9_L001_plasmidspades_careful`

I want to rename them to just the `10-00017_S9_L001` part

I've tried to use the cut command `echo "$filename" | cut -d'_' -f3`, however that leaves me with just the L001 part of the filename.

Obviously I could just rename them all manually, but there are hundreds of directories and I have not got the time.

Is there a way to use the cut command to get everything before the specific instance of the delimiter, or indeed anything else I could use?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use `rename` (Debian) or `prename` (RedHat) (same command, different name)(these packages could have to be added from the standard distro repos). It uses regular expressions (Perl-style). For instance, trying to be a bit strict on the match:

```
rename -n 's/(\d+_\d+_S\d_L\d+)_.+/$1/' *
```

or a more lenient:

```
rename -n 's/(.+_.+_.+_.+)_.+/$1/' *
```

With `-n` it just shows what it would do, remove (or better, replace by `-v`) for actual execution.

Note the single quotes around the pattern to avoid bash substitution on backslashes and dollars.

Comment: In is Larry Wall's `rename`. Some systems have a different `rename`. `rename` is `sed` for file-names.

Answer (score 0):

A rather low tech solution:

- Use `ls` or `find` to create a list of directory in a file
- Use an editor you are familiar with to replace each line (that just contains `oldname` by `mv oldname newname`)
- Execute the script:

  ```
  . list_of_moves
  ```

  (note leading dot-space)

Answer (score 0):

Put all directories in one file and execute below command to get it renamed

```
awk '{print "mv"  " "   $1  " " substr($1,1,16)}' filename | sh
```

Tested for above mentioned dirtectoy and it worked fine

```
echo "10-00017_S9_L001_plasmidspades_careful" | awk '{print "mv"  " "   $1  " " substr($1,1,16)}' | sh
```